# Используем calc() в Less?

Tags: css3, less

Возможно ли в less, при данном условии width: ~"calc ((100% / 3) -20px)", получить на выходе в css

не — width: calc ((100% / 3) -20px)";

а — width: calc(41.66666666666667% - 20px);

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вроде бы возможно, но расскажите, как именно вы запускаете-подключаете less, чтобы ответ был точнее

Comment: Less у меня работает через gulp

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое, добавить переменную и вставить ее в calc("Переменная хранящая (100% / 3)" - 20px)

Comment: Разобрался уже: переменная, percentage